# Local final class <no name provided> issue for throwable: Class<out Throwable> in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have some problems when trying to migrate my java methods to project with kotlin. I have a method with next signature:

```
public static RetryTemplate getRetryTemplate(long initialInterval, int maxAttempts, Class<? extends Throwable> throwable) { .... }
```

or in Kotlin:

```
fun getRetryTemplate(initialInterval: Long, maxAttempts: Int, throwable: Class<out Throwable>): RetryTemplate? {
```

When I'm trying to call this method in Kotlin code I get a compiler issue - Local final class no name provided (see screenshot)

```
RetryUtils.getRetryTemplate(5000, 3, Exception.class)
```

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It is required to use Exception::class.java

why Intellij not recommended this solution?

Comment: This is the least of the problems. The main question is why IntelliJ consumes a lot of CPU resources even when not running the application.

Comment: It's off-topic) Intellij the application itself and consumes a lot of resources